# c# - RadioGroupBox Data-Binding to enum (Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, enums, radio-group

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksCzJ.png

I'm trying to get a two way binding between an enum and a RadioGroupBox in winforms, c#. To make things worse, the enum is in a different class:

```
public enum SizingOptions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Grow all dimensions equally.
    /// </summary>
    GrowBoth,

    /// <summary>
    /// Grow width only.
    /// </summary>
    GrowWidth,

    /// <summary>
    /// Grow length only.
    /// </summary>
    GrowLength
}
```

I've declared an instance of the enum:

```
public SizingOptions SquareSizing { get; set; }
```

I've also bound it Manually in the constructor in the MainForm class:

```
grpSquare.DataBindings.Add("Selected", concreteColumnSizerWorkerBindingSource, "SquareSizing");
```

Currently it's not working. What can I do to? I've tried binding in the designer to the tag

Comment: what is `RadioGroupBox`? Custom control?

Comment: it's a combination of GroupBox and Radio Buttons (Basically radio buttons in a GroupBox)